# How can I echo the value of a windows system variable inside Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: windows, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

For example: when I echo %APPDATA% on cmd line is expected to print the path to appdata folder, like this: "C:\Users\User\AppData". How can I do the same in a jenkins pipeline?

```
def app1 = "%APPDATA%"
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo ¨\¨${app1}\¨"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following methods should work.

```
echo "${APPDATA}"

echo "${env.APPDATA}"

echo "$APPDATA"
```